# bars missing when using shiny to create ggplot bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, bar-chart

I used shiny and created a `app.R` file to hope to build a bar chart with `ggplot`. I also used `checkboxGroupInput` to create a 2 check boxes to control the condition. While the total number of bars should be 28 after all boxes are checked, but the maximum seemed to allow only 17 bars for some reason. So some bars (row of data) are missing. The missing bars don't seems to have a pattern. Can someone please help ?

dataset:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fUQk_vMJWPwWnIMbXvyd5ro_HBk-DBfc

my code:

```
midterm <- read.csv('midterm-results.csv')

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# get column number for response time
k <- c(33:88)
v <- c()

for (i in k){
        if (i%%2 == 1){
                v <- c(v,i)
        }
}


#average response time by question
time <- midterm[ , v]
new.col.name <- gsub('_.*', "", colnames(time))
colnames(time) <- new.col.name
avg.time <- data.frame(apply(time, 2, mean))
avg.time$question <- rownames(avg.time)
colnames(avg.time) <- c('response_time', 'question')
rownames(avg.time) <- NULL
avg.time$question <- factor(avg.time$question, 
                            levels = c('Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q5','Q6','Q7','Q8.9',
                                       'Q10','Q11','Q12.13','Q14','Q15','Q16','Q17',
                                       'Q18','Q19','Q20','Q21','Q22','Q23','Q24','Q25',
                                       'Q26','Q27','Q28','Q29','Q30'))

avg.time$question_type <-  c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)
# I did this manually because the there when data was imported into the  midterm.csv,
# q8 & 9, q12 &13 were accidentally merged (28 v.s 30 question)

avg.time$question_type <- ifelse(avg.time$question_type == 1,
                                 'googleable', 'not googleable')
avg.time$question_type <- factor(avg.time$question_type,
                                 levels = c('googleable', 'not googleable'))


library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


ui <- fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "type",
                       label = "select question type", 
                       choices = levels(avg.time$question_type),
                       selected = TRUE), 
    plotOutput('bar')
    )

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$bar <- renderPlot({
         ggplot(avg.time[avg.time$question_type==input$type, ], 
                aes(x=question, response_time)) +
             geom_bar(aes(fill = question_type), stat='identity', width = 0.5)
    }, height =500, width = 1000)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


ui <- fluidPage(
     checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "type", label = "select question type", 
                 choices = levels(avg.time$question_type), selected = TRUE), 
     plotOutput('bar')
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive(avg.time[avg.time$question_type %in% input$type, ])
  output$bar <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(data(), 
       aes(x=question, response_time)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', width = 0.5, 
                                                  aes(fill = question_type))

 }, height =500, width = 1000)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

of course you can use avg.time[avg.time$question_type %in% input$type, ] inside ggplot2 but reactivity is better.

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem is resolved. But I am wondering why `%in%` and e `==` will make such a big difference? What are they telling  R to do differently?

Comment: I'm also a newbie to R Loool, but I think `==` expect and knows how to make a comparison to a single element. In the other side `%in%` expect and knows how to make a comparison to a single and a set of elements  "many". Put `observe(print(input$type))` in the server function and check what print out in the console. I hope you got my idea and it's much clear for you now.

Comment: @EdwardLin glad to help you. Please accept my answer if you find it helpful. Thank you